# How to upload records to Postgres Master Database?

Tags: database, postgresql, etl

I have 5 exact same Postgres database at 5 locations. I would like to upload (real time or every night) records from each database to a 6th Remote Master Database of same structure (one way upload only, no need to sync back).

in this way I will have their own respective data on 5 database and all the records from 5 databases in 6th Database.

How can I achieve this with Postgres? I have some clues about ETL but no idea on how to implement the same.

Any Help on this will be highly appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: When they are the "exact same" you mean they have the exact same schema, but different data? Do they have any unique columns such as primary keys or unique constraints? What would you like to do about deletes?

Comment: This is a repeat of here [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71498635/how-to-one-way-sync-data-from-local-database-server-to-master-database-of-a-pos).  Delete that question. This question still borders on the opinion-based and will probably get the same close votes you got before. To prevent that update the question with specific details as @Schwern suggested.